# Run-time error with WebBrowser Control "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: vba, excel, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to write a code that opens up a web browser and selects a series of buttons, however after the webpage opens I get this error:

**Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)
Automation error: The object invoked has disconneted from its clients**

The webpage I'm using is only one that can be accessed from my server so maybe that could be it?  The webpage opens fine, it's when it gets to the ReadyState line of code is when I get the error.  The code works fine with google and other webpages, but I'm having a real issue with this one.  Below is my code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.AddressBar = 0
objIE.StatusBar = 0
objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True 

objIE.Navigate ("https://mxf85.mcmnt.cbs.edu/")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

        pageSource = objIE.Document.body.Outerhtml

                objIE.Document.GetElementByID("haQuickSearchBox").Value = "Insurance"
                 objIE.Document.GetElementByID("Submit").Click
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: On which ReadyState occurrence are you getting the error? The first or the second?

Comment: The first one, sorry I should have specified.

Comment: a dumb question: is there a _result_ webpage you can directly call? just looking at the html-source-code may give you some hints to access the site with `https://address/index.html?[name of element]=[value of element]&[name of element 2]=[value of element 2]...`